# Error: not enough outputs for specified ring size = 11

Tags: ringct, ringsize, monero-forks

I am trying to fork `monero release-v0.13`. I have made changes to the cryptonote_config file and I built and ran the daemon. Everything seems to be fine, nodes are syncing, mining is happening. But when I try to transfer an amount using wallet-cli, I am getting the below error.

`Error: not enough outputs for specified ring size = 11:`

I have been trying to fix this for the past 3 days.

I have searched in google but I didn't find any solution. Can anyone please help.

Comment: How many blocks have you mined?

Comment: I have mined 95 blocks so far

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find 10 outputs on the blockchain other than your own with the same amount, so they can all be put in a ring. Your daemon is telling you it could not find that many. Not surprising if you start with a fresh chain. Use a smaller ring size.

Comment: I tried with ring size 1, the command is `transfer 1  <address> 10` but I got the this error
`Error: ring size 1 is too small, minimum is 11`

Comment: Ring size 1 is ok iff the inputs aren't mixable. Ring size 11 otherwise. You say you're trying to fork monero though, did you try to change the consensus rules ? If so, you probably did it wrong